# How to avoid newlines caused by conditionals?

Tags: go, formatting, go-templates

Given this Go text/template code:

```
Let's say:
{{ if eq .Foo "foo" }}
Hello, StackOverflow!
{{ else if eq .Foo "bar" }}
Hello, World!
{{ end }}
```

We get the following output in case `Foo` equals `"foo"`:

```
Let's say:

Hello, StackOverflow!
```

(followed by a newline)

Is there a way to get rid of the extra newlines?

I would expect that this can be accomplished using the `{{-` and `-}}` syntax:

```
Let's say:
{{- if eq .Foo "foo" }}
Hello, StackOverflow!
{{- else if eq .Foo "bar" }}
Hello, World!
{{- end }}
```

However, that yields an `illegal number syntax: "-"` error.

Comment: Are you sure you got the error? I copy-paste the template in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iNaEYCMn2D), it works as expected. Probably you forgot to put `space` between `-` and `syntax`.

Comment: Maybe your go version is too old? As far as I remember this is a new feature.

Comment: @SvenWalter you are correct, it was introduced [since 1.6](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#template)

Comment: @putu I'll double-check.

Comment: @SvenWalter pebcak -- it was actually Go 1.5 running on that machine

Comment: Adding the "-" before the if/end worked for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your first template, you have a newline after the static text `"Let's say:"`, and the 2nd line contains only the `{{if}}` action, and it also contains a newline, and its body `"Hello, StackOverflow!"` starts in the 3rd line. If this is rendered, there will be 2 newlines between the 2 static texts, so you'll see an empty line (as you posted).

You may use `{{- if...` to get rid of the first newline, so when rendered, only 1 newline gets to the output, resulting in 2 different lines but no newlines between them:

```
Let's say:
{{- if eq .Foo "foo" }}
Hello, StackOverflow!
{{- else if eq .Foo "bar" }}
Hello, World!
{{- end }}
```

Output when `Foo` is `"foo"`:

```
Let's say:
Hello, StackOverflow!
```

Output when `Foo` is `"bar"`:

```
Let's say:
Hello, World!
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TN1o7qe778).

Note that this was added in [Go 1.6: Template](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#template), and is documented at [`text/template`: Text and Spaces](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Text_and_spaces).

If you use the `-` sign at the closing of the actions `-}}`, you can even remove all the newlines:

```
Let's say:
{{- if eq .Foo "foo" -}}
Hello, StackOverflow!
{{- else if eq .Foo "bar" -}}
Hello, World!
{{- end -}}
```

Output when `Foo` is `"foo"` and `Foo` is `"bar"`:

```
Let's say:Hello, StackOverflow!
Let's say:Hello, World!
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SsCVKej9UD).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as this is obviously how we expect to solve this since Go 1.6. +1 for also explaining variations. In my case, the problem was an old Go version floating around, which shouldn't normally happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new line because you're adding a new line after colons (:)

This works https://play.golang.org/p/k4lazGhE-r
Note I just start the first **if** right after the first colons

Comment: Technically, this solution is correct. However, I'd like to keep the newlines in the template to improve readability.